# inserting null as Integer value into a database

Tags: android, database

I am trying to store a null value into the database but everytime I load the value I get 0.

I declare the field just like "`intVal integer"`

This is how I retrieve it:

```
Integer x;

x = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBAdapter.KEY_X));
```

Is that reliable? or is it undefined?

So it seems to me one cannot save null as an undefined integervalue

Many thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [the `getInt()` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29):

> Returns the value of the requested column as an int.
>   The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null, the column type is not an integral type, or the integer value is outside the range [Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE] is implementation-defined.

So, it's an implementation detail which you shouldn't rely on.

You can still get the effect you want, though: you simply do the null check before you read the value.

```java
int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBAdapter.KEY_X);
Integer x = null;
if (!cursor.isNull(index)
    x = cursor.getInt(index);

// now x is either null or contains a valid value
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is dynamically typed. Since you defined column of type Integer and it didn't find a value it returned 0 based on the hint.

Try using String as the type of column

Comment: What happens if you want to know if the field stored was empty rather then zero? How do you tell the difference here?

Answer (score 0):

As Rajdeep Dua mentioned, SQLite uses a dynamic typing. Here's what the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) says:

> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than
>   SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static
>   typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the
>   particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
>   datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
>   container.

The Android documentation says that the result of [getInt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29) when the column value is `null` is implementation defined. For me, it returns 0 as well.

So I used [getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)) instead, although the result of this method is also implementation defined, for me, it returns `null` when the column value is `null`, or a string containing the number otherwise.

So the code looks like this:

```
Strint strVal = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDBAdapter.KEY_X));

if(strVal != null){
    int intVal = Integer.parseInt(strVal);
}
```

Comment: It should be cursor.getString() not cursor.getInt()