# Getting null ints from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an issue that may in fact be a design issue but I am struggling to find a way around it.

In my sqlite database in my android application, I have a table called `Customer`. This has around 40 columns of various string and int data types. In practice, any of these columns may or may not be null.

In my code, I have a function simply called `getCustomer()`, which queries the database for a specific customer, and places all their cells from the database into a `Customer` class, which contains variables for each column. I can then pass that customer object around as I wish. The `getCustomer()` function returns this `Customer` object.

My problem is integers which may be null. I am familiar with how `int` cannot be null in java, but how `Integer` can be null. But my problem actually lies in the fact that the *cells in the database* can be empty (eg null).

For string columns, I simply do this:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.firstName = cursor.getString(0);
```

If `cursor.getString(0);` returns a null value, then the `firstName` variable is assigned null. Nice and simple. However with an int:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.daysSinceJoining = cursor.getInt(5);
```

The above crashes at run-time if `daysSinceJoining` is null. So I tried the following:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
if (cursor.getInt(5) != null)
    cust.daysSinceJoining = cursor.getInt(5);
```

However this gives me a compiler error, as you cannot use an `int` in a null comparison like that.

How can I get around this problem? How can I retrieve an int from an sqlite database when the int value *could* be null?

Comment: check what is value of cursor.getInt(5) ..I think it is 0 . if it is zero then proceed according to that

Comment: int default value is 0 so you should check that getting value is equal zeor or not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could  try the `isNull()` function.

Answer (score 15):

@sanders is right about the [`isNull()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isNull%28int%29) method and here's how you edit your code to use it:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
if (!cursor.isNull(5))
    cust.daysSinceJoining = cursor.getInt(5);
```

Answer (score 7):

Please take a look to that answer:

[getInt null-constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063768/inserting-null-as-integer-value-into-a-database)

I think that should work for you:

```
int lIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN);
Integer lInteger = null;
if (!cursor.isNull(lIndex)
lInteger = cursor.getInt(lIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cursor wrapper and add new functionality to the cursor class:

```
public class CustomCursor extends CursorWrapper {

    public CustomCursor(Cursor cursor) { super(cursor); } //simple constructor

    public Integer getInteger(int columnIndex) { // new method to return Integer instead of int
        if (super.isNull(columnIndex)){
            return null;
        }else{
            return super.getInt(columnIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Cursor defaultCursor = db.rawQuery("select null,2 ", null);
defaultCursor.moveToFirst();
CustomCursor customCursor = new CustomCursor(defaultCursor);
customCursor.moveToFirst(); //custom cursor can do anything that default cursor can do

int defaultInt0 = defaultCursor.getInt(0); //nulls are usually converted into zero
int defaultInt1 = defaultCursor.getInt(1); //2 is correct

int customInt0 = customCursor.getInt(0); //these 2 are same as above , ie zero and 2
int customInt1 = customCursor.getInt(1);

Integer customInteger0 = customCursor.getInteger(0); // this will give a null Integer
Integer customInteger1 = customCursor.getInteger(1); // this will give a 2 Integer

Log.v("custom log.v call ", "lets see what outputs, null is usually converted to the word 'null' by the String.valueOf method :"
        +String.valueOf(defaultInt0)+","+String.valueOf(defaultInt1)+","
        +String.valueOf(customInt0)+","+String.valueOf(customInt1)+","
        +String.valueOf(customInteger0)+","+String.valueOf(customInteger1)
); 
//V: lets see what outputs, null is usually converted to the word 'null' by the String.valueOf method :0,2,0,2,null,2
```

Answer (score -2):

if (cursor.getInt(5) !=0){

```
cust.daysSinceJoining = cursor.getInt(5);
```

}

or

```
int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
Integer x = null;
if (!cursor.isNull(index)
   cust.daysSinceJoining = cursor.getInt(5);
}
```

see the documentation
 [getInt() documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt%28int%29)

Comment: This does not help. `cursor.getInt()` returns an `int` and when boxed in `Integer` it will always be non-`null`. Also `Integer` does not have `isNull()` method.

Comment: I do not know Why I am getting minus rattings.Anyone pls explain why my answer is worng