# simple SQL query using rawQuery and WHERE clause issue

Tags: android, sql

I have to exec a simple query like:

```
SELECT messages.*, contacts.nick FROM messages INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.userId = messages.userId WHERE messages.isListened=0
```

where `isListened` is declared as `INTEGER`:

```
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
...
            Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED + " INTEGER, " +
...
```

And I cant make it work. What I had tried already:

```
        private static final String getAllMessagesSQL = 
            "SELECT "
                +Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+".*, "
                +Tables.Contacts.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Contacts.NICK
            +" FROM "+Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME
            +" INNER JOIN "+Tables.Contacts.TABLE_NAME
                +" ON "+Tables.Contacts.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Contacts.USER_ID+" = "
                    + Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.SENDER_USER_ID
            +" WHERE "+Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED+"='0'";
    public void getAllMessages(final List<Message> list) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        Message message = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            db = dbAdapter.openToRead();
            cursor = db.rawQuery(getAllMessagesSQL, null);
            Log.w(this,"getAllMessages(): \nsql: "+getAllMessagesSQL+"\ncursor.getCount(): "+cursor.getCount());
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                list.clear();
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    Log.w(this, "getAllMessages() message.IS_LISTENED: "+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED)));
                    message = getMessageFromCursor(cursor);
                    list.add(message);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
...
```

The result is:

```
05-26 11:06:20.706: W/DatabaseHelper(3352): getAllMessages(): 
05-26 11:06:20.706: W/DatabaseHelper(3352): sql: SELECT messages.*, contacts.nick FROM messages INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.userId = messages.userId WHERE messages.isListened='0'
05-26 11:06:20.706: W/DatabaseHelper(3352): cursor.getCount(): 0
```

Also I had tried the `WHERE` clause without quoting the 0:

```
...
    +" WHERE "+Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED+"=0";
...
```

And in a proper way like:

```
...
+" WHERE "+Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED+"=?";
...
            cursor = db.rawQuery(getAllMessagesSQL, new String[]{"0"});
```

and result is the same - 0 records while I know there are 2 of them.
 
To make sure if I comment out the `WHERE` clause like:

```
...                 + Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.SENDER_USER_ID;
            //+" WHERE "+Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED+"='0'";
....
```

then I got the following output:

```
05-26 11:12:14.046: W/DatabaseHelper(3635): getAllMessages(): 
05-26 11:12:14.046: W/DatabaseHelper(3635): sql: SELECT messages.*, contacts.nick FROM messages INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.userId = messages.userId
05-26 11:12:14.046: W/DatabaseHelper(3635): cursor.getCount(): 2
05-26 11:12:14.046: W/DatabaseHelper(3635): getAllMessages() message.IS_LISTENED: 0
05-26 11:12:14.046: W/DatabaseHelper(3635): getAllMessages() message.IS_LISTENED: 0
```

So as you can see there are 2 recs matched if no WHERE clause is used.
 
So why the WHERE caluse doesn't work here?

Comment: May it be, that there is a value in db that is mapped to 0 but is not the value 0 (like null)?

Comment: You are right, adding NULL check fixed the issue. I thought that INTEGER can't be null by default in sql...

Comment: Why not if it is not declared as `NOT NULL` also an integer can be `null`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054182/getting-null-ints-from-sqlite-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `WHERE "+Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED+"=0 OR " +Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME+"."+Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED+" IS NULL"`

or change

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Tables.Messages.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
...
            Tables.Messages.IS_LISTENED + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
...
```

Comment: you have to define it while creating table, I will update this answer